# Узнать удаленность от точки А до дочки Б для маршрута авто

Tags: php, карты, геолокация

Есть точка А, её координаты статичны.

Посетитель указывает своё местоположение - Б, после чего происходит расчёт расстояния между точками А и Б, ключевой момент, необходимо не кратчайшее расстояние между точками, а расстояние по маршруту следования авто от А к Б.

Я так понимаю копать нужно в сторону api каких нибудь карт (гугл, яндекс - предпочтительней).

Кто сталкивался с такой задачей - жду ваших комментариев, ответов, уговоров что так делать не надо и это головная боль :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это апи называется - алгебра, где можно по вычислить длину вектора по его координатам.

Comment: расстояние будет правильным, если мы на самолете перемешаемся =)

Comment: А в апи есть функция поиск кротчайшего пути?

Comment: Даа, или на вертолёте, но увы перемещаемся мы на авто :)
Я исправил вопрос, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение.

Comment: @nMike хороший вопрос :)

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/127999/

Comment: Гуд, то что доктор прописал!